# Pause any mediaplayer on some event

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player

I have created an application that read messages with voice. I would like to pause any running media player when a message arrives in order to make the voice more clear. Is there any intent that could achieve this aim? I have noticed that google navigator, for example, is able to pause media player (and other music app like pandora).

Thanks in advance
Tobia Loschiavo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an intent, but have you tried AudioManager and [requestAudioFocus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)?

Sadly its only from API 8